# Can't connect to 2 different Linux computers via VNC (local network)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, vnc

I have a problem connecting to Vino VNC server with 2 Linux Computers running Xubuntu.

The computers are Based on the ODroid U3 chip which is ARM based.
When both of the ODroids are on the same network VNC fails, 
When I turn off one of them I can connect to the other,
As VNC is the main display for these computers, this is important.

Here's the IFConfig for ODroid1 (The old ODroid U3)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1e:f6:d7:be:00:ad  
          inet addr:192.168.1.62  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1cf6:d7ff:febe:ad/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:578475 (578.4 KB)  TX bytes:1550098 (1.5 MB)
```

Here's the IFConfig for ODroid2 (The new ODroid U3)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1e:f6:d7:be:00:ae  
          inet addr:192.168.1.64  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1cf6:d7ff:febe:ae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:146660 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:174482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:104504282 (104.5 MB)  TX bytes:112083194 (112.0 MB)
```

One more note from my experience, if I turn the old ODroid and then connect the new one, 
I can reconnect the old and have a couple of minutes connected to both via VNC, however this eventually fails
WIth the same error... here's the error I get via VNC when both Odroid's are online and I try to connect the new one:

```
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM Pixel format for client tzvi-lap-linux.local:
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM   16 bpp, depth 16, little endian
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM   true colour: max r 31 g 63 b 31, shift r 11 g 5 b 0
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type -131072
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client tzvi-lap-linux.local
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type -131071
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type -131070
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type -131069
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type -309
03/04/2014 01:33:11 AM Enabling cursor position and shape (rich encoding) updates for client tzvi-lap-linux.local
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
vino-server: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
odroid@odroid-office:~$
```

Please help me connecting both via VNC on the same network?

Comment: do you connect to both from the same host, or from two separate hosts? (I am thinking maybe the problem is at client, not server)

Comment: Sverre: Tried both situations, same host or different host on the network doesn't matter - also the problem only occur when these two are live together, I just shutdown one of them so I can connect the other

Comment: I have an update on this issue as it might be client related, I have now successfully connected to the VNC while both are online from my VNC client on my cellphone - could this be Remmina's error?

Comment: I think it is most likely a client error yes. maybe try another than Rammina ?

Comment: I just tried 2 different clints including realVNC, and vinagre - both kill the vino server with the same error:
`05/04/2014 04:17:29 AM Client returned security type 2
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
vino-server: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion !xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost failed.
/usr/local/bin/vino: line 3:  3125 Aborted                 (core dumped) /usr/lib/vino/vino-server`

What the hell is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem doesn't occur on X11VNC,
I have switched VNC servers on one of the computers and the problem did not reoccur.